# MySQL SELECT *and* LIMIT RAND() range possible?

Tags: mysql, random

I'm trying to pull a random number of records from MySQL between a range, say 100 and 500.

This works:

```
SELECT  *,
        FLOOR(RAND() * (500-100) + 100) AS 'RandomValue'
FROM    sample
ORDER   BY RAND()
```

Except that pulls an enormous dataset.

What I'd really like to do is this:

```
SELECT  *,
        FLOOR(RAND() * (500-100) + 100) AS 'RandomValue'
FROM    sample
ORDER   BY RAND()
LIMIT   'RandomValue'
```

so I'm getting a different number of records every time.

(I'm ensuring uniqueness elsewhere.)

How the fsck is this done?

** EDIT: The note that this is a duplicate question already answered is entirely incorrect. No idea who/how things get flagged thusly, but it's wrong: this question is neither a duplicate nor something that has been answered.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Should have thunk to include version in my post:



MariaDB v10.5.8

Comment: Don't get used to single quote identifiers like column aliases. In standard SQL and many other DBMS single quotes are only for string (and date ...) literals. And even in MySQL, which is sadly accepting that in general, in some cases the outcome might not be what you actually want.

Comment: Does the set also have to be random or just the *number* of records?

Comment: @stickybit Both the quantity and the records themselves need to be random.

Once we have the random records, they're going into another table for further processing.

We're also then updating the original table to ensure uniqueness (removed this restriction to keep the example query easier to follow).